# If $[\mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]=n$, then $n \mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ be a number field and $\mathcal
O_K$ be its ring of integers. Show that if $[\mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]=n$, then $n \mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

I don't know how to approach this question. Is it helpful to look at an example of such $\mathcal{O}_K, \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$? Maybe I can consider some roots of quadratic or cubic polynomial.

Comment: This is almost obvious for abelian groups $G,H$. If $[G:H]=n$, then $nH \subseteq G$.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the result of applying Lagrange's theorem to the abelian group $\mathcal O_K/\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ (which has order $n$); and as the user Crostul points out, the statement holds for any normal subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ with $[G:N]=n$.

Comment: But I'm seeking $nG \subseteq H$ not $nH \subseteq G$ where $G=\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

Comment: @JasonDil my hint will give you the solution you want. Crosul's comment has a typo.